# Closure and nested lambdas in C++0x

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, visual-c++-2010

Using C++0x, how do I capture a variable when I have a lambda within a lambda?  For example:

```
std::vector<int> c1;
int v = 10; <--- I want to capture this variable

std::for_each(
    c1.begin(),
    c1.end(),
    [v](int num) <--- This is fine...
    {
        std::vector<int> c2;

        std::for_each(
            c2.begin(),
            c2.end(),
            [v](int num) <--- error on this line, how do I recapture v?
            {
                // Do something
            });
    });
```

Comment: I would guess assigning the variable in the first closure might help.

Comment: The above is fine on gcc4.5 - are you using VC10?

Comment: Yes, VC10.  I shall report it to Microsoft.

Comment: Sounds good, i don't see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Especially since this works for VC#, wrote by the same company.

Comment: Different team, different standard.

Comment: [Microsoft Connect entry](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560907/capturing-variables-in-nested-lambdas).

Comment: Any idea if this is fixed? @DanDan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::for_each(
        c1.begin(),
        c1.end(),
        [&](int num)
        {
            std::vector<int> c2;
            int& v_ = v;
            std::for_each(
                c2.begin(),
                c2.end(),
                [&](int num)
                {
                    v_ = num;
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Not especially clean, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, hopefully this will be fixed in a later version.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with is this:

```
std::vector<int> c1;
int v = 10; 

std::for_each(
    c1.begin(),
    c1.end(),
    [v](int num) 
    {
        std::vector<int> c2;
        int vv=v;

        std::for_each(
            c2.begin(),
            c2.end(),
            [&](int num) // <-- can replace & with vv
            {
                int a=vv;
            });
    });
```

Interesting problem! I'll sleep on it and see if i can figure something better out.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner lambda you should have(assuming you want to pass the variable by reference):

```
[&v](int num)->void{

  int a =v;
}
```