# Error c3867 in c++ Can't figure it out

Tags: c++, glut

I've been in every thread on this subject and i still can't fix this error
this is GameManager.h

```
void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
void myDisplay(void);
void myBoardKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void timer(int millisec);
void speedtime(int speed);
void FPS(void);
void myIdle();
void mySpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y);
```

This is GameManager.cpp
i have all the functions above declared like this

```
void GameManager::myBoardKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y){....}
void GameManager::timer(int millisec){....}
```

this is my main function

```
    GameManager* _game = new GameManager();
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// main() function
// ----------------------------------------------------------
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(INIT_WINDOW_W, INIT_WINDOW_H);
    glutInitWindowPosition(-1, -1);
    glutCreateWindow("The Frogger");
    glutIdleFunc(_game->myIdle);//C3867
    glutDisplayFunc(_game->myDisplay);//C3867
    glutReshapeFunc(_game->GameManager::myReshape);//C3867
    glutSpecialFunc(_game->mySpecialKeys);//C3867
    glutKeyboardFunc(_game->myBoardKeys);//C3867
    _game->timer(rand() % 1000);//C3867
    glutTimerFunc(10000, _game->speedtime, 10000);//C3867
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I've tried to call it like

```
&GameManager::myIdle
&_game->myIdle
```

it still gives me the same error, and i can't see why.

hope you guys can help me with this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are those free functions? If so, why are you trying to feed them through the _game pointer?

Comment: you are calling it wrong. You should call it `_game->myIdle()` given your `myIdle is a function. Your `_game` is a pointer pointing to an object that has member function `myIdle()`Also, I am assuming your `myIdle` is a public or protected function - not private (pointless to call then).

Comment: They are all public functions, also _game->myIdle() does not work it returns argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (__cdecl *)()" i forgot to mention that all those functions are supposed to be callbacks, if i put them all on my main file they work, but the teacher wants them out of the main, and he doesn't know how to solve this lol

Comment: Please search for "c++ member function as callback", you'll find lots of info as to why what you're doing can't work, and workarounds.

Comment: You will have to make your members as static functions. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769009/how-to-get-classs-function-pointer-for-non-static-function-from-another-classs. Or use advance features like bind or function. Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/de-de/fe3bf6cc-61e6-455c-bb83-288c774dfc72/c3867-on-attempting-to-pass-function-pointer-to-method?forum=vclanguage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out guys thanks!! 
this is the solution this is the GameManager.h

```
static float R, W, H;
int timespeed = 35;
static GLint gFramesPerSecond;

static void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
static void myDisplay(void);
static void myBoardKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
static void timer(int millisec);
static void speedtime(int speed);
static void FPS(void);
static void myIdle();
static void mySpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y);
```

this is the GameManager.cpp

```
float GameManager::R, GameManager::H, GameManager::W;
GLint GameManager::gFramesPerSecond;
Jogo* GameManager::_jogo = new Jogo();
void GameManager::myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h){...}
Rest of functions here....
```

and this is my main

```
 void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(INIT_WINDOW_W, INIT_WINDOW_H);
    glutInitWindowPosition(-1, -1);
    glutCreateWindow("The Frogger");
    glutIdleFunc(GameManager::myIdle);
    glutDisplayFunc(GameManager::myDisplay);
    glutReshapeFunc(GameManager::myReshape);
    glutSpecialFunc(GameManager::mySpecialKeys);
    glutKeyboardFunc(GameManager::myBoardKeys);
    GameManager::timer(rand() % 1000);
    glutTimerFunc(10000, GameManager::speedtime, 10000);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

i had to make everything static, and it now works

Thanks!